# Laravel 5 eloquent chunk data

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, query-optimization

I have in table is more 50000 records. Relationship Many To Many.

Records model:

```
 public function busines(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Busines', 'busines_record', 'record_id', 'busines_id');
    }
```

Busines model:

```
 public function records()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Record', 'record_id');
    }
```

My query:

```
 $data = Records::with('busines')->where('show', '=', 1)->get();
```

Query is long execute. How optimize query ?

Comment: Try adding basic index to the `show` field. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/migrations#creating-indexes

Answer (score 0):

You can paginate it:

```
$records = Records::with('busines')->where('show', '=', 1)->paginate();
```

and show the pagination in the view with:

```
{!! $records->links() !!}
```

Or you can use chunk (see [query builder docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/queries#retrieving-results) "Chunking Results From A Table"):

```
Records::with('busines')->chunk(100, function($records) {
    foreach ($records as $record) {
        dump($record->id);
    }
});
```

Comment: I use datatables plugin jquery, package  https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables. How return result use chunk in Datatables::of($data)->make(true) ?

Comment: That plugin has support for pagination, does that not solve your problem? How many records do you show per page?